# invalid format error when trying to ssh into pulumi-created azure nextgen vm

Tags: typescript, azure, ssh, pulumi

I'm trying to create & ssh into a virtual machine created with the azure nextgen Pulumi api. I am running Window 10.

After I successfully create the VM, for testing purposes I am exporting the private key to a file, reducing the permissions to avoid the 'permissions too open' error, and then running `ssh user@ip -i keyfile.rsa`. However, I receive the error: `Load key ... invalid format.`

The relevant script is as follows:

```
const rsaKey = new tls.PrivateKey("rsaKey", {
    algorithm: "RSA",
});

const vm = new azure_nextgen.compute.latest.VirtualMachine("vm", {
    location: resourceGroup.location,
    resourceGroupName: resourceGroup.name,
    vmName: "linuxvm",
    hardwareProfile: {
        vmSize: "Standard_B1ms", // may go up to standard b2ms
    },
    networkProfile: {
        networkInterfaces: [{
            id: networkInterface.id,
        }]
    },
    osProfile: {
        adminUsername: vmUser,
        computerName: "test-vm",
        linuxConfiguration: {
            disablePasswordAuthentication: true,
            ssh: {
                publicKeys: [{
                    keyData: rsaKey.publicKeyOpenssh,
                    path: "/home/*username*/.ssh/authorized_keys",
                }]
            }
        }
    },
    storageProfile: {
        imageReference: {
            offer: "UbuntuServer",
            publisher: "Canonical",
            sku: "18.04-LTS",
            version: "latest",
        },
        osDisk: {
            caching: "ReadWrite",
            createOption: "FromImage",
            managedDisk: {
                storageAccountType: "Standard_LRS",
            },
            name: "myVMosdisk",
        },
    }
})
```

I

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts on things to check:

- If you enable password access and login to the instance, do you see the public key under the given user as per your code?
- When you save the private key locally, is it formatted correctly - so it looks like this block format when you look at the file?

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAAAaAAAABNlY2RzYS
1zaGEyLW5pc3RwMjU2AAAACG5pc3RwMjU2AAAAQQR9WZPeBSvixkhjQOh9yCXXlEx5CN9M
yh94CJJ1rigf8693gc90HmahIR5oMGHwlqMoS7kKrRw+4KpxqsF7LGvxAAAAqJZtgRuWbY
....
EbAAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBH1Zk94FK+LGSGNA
6H3IJdeUTHkI30zKH3gIknWuKB/zr3eBz3QeZqEhHmgwYfCWoyhLuQqtHD7gqnGqwXssa/
EAAAAgBzKpRmMyXZ4jnSt3ARz0ul6R79AXAr5gQqDAmoFeEKwAAAAOYWpAYm93aWUubG9j
YWwBAg==
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: yes, if I generate my own keypair and hardcode the public key in the script I can access instance fine and see the public key in the correct file.


Yes, it's formated as BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY, but its wellformed I believe

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example bit of code that generates the key and then writes it to a file which can then be used with `ssh -i ...`
Note the use of `.apply()` to render the key value. Without that the file written will basically contain an error/help message and not the private key.

```
const sshKey = new tls.PrivateKey(`${projectName}-sshkey`, {
    algorithm: "RSA",
});
const privateKeyPem = sshKey.privateKeyPem.apply(key => {
    fs.writeFile('privateKeyPem', key, (err) => {
        console.log("privateKeyPem saved")
    })
})
```

Your VM declaration looks fine. But just to confirm, I assume the `*username*` that you show in the path in the VM's ssh block is actually set to the value you are using for the `adminusername` parameter above that. If not, those need to match.